# How to get if an observer is registered in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to remove an observer after it run or when the view dissapeared. Here is the code but sometimes the observer was already removed when i want to remove it again. How to check if it is still registered?

```
 override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if(!didOnce){
        if(keyPath == "myLocation"){
            location = mapView.myLocation.coordinate;

            self.mapView.animateToLocation(self.location!);
            self.mapView.animateToZoom(15);
            didOnce = true;
            self.mapView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "myLocation");
        }
    }
}
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    didOnce = false;
}
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    if(!didOnce){

        self.mapView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "myLocation");
        didOnce = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're on the right track. Add an `isObserving` property to your class. Set it to true when you start observing, and set it to false when you stop observing. In all cases check the flag before starting/stopping observing to make sure you are not already in that state.

You can also add a willSet method to the property and have that code start/stop observing when the property changes states.

Answer (score 1):

Main reason: addObserver() is called 1 time (at viewDidLoad or init), but removeObserver() can be called 2 times or more (base on the times viewWillDisappear() was called).

To resolve: move addObserver() to viewWillAppear():

```
private var didOnce = false

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.mapView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "myLocation", options: .new, context: nil)
}

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if(!didOnce){
        if(keyPath == "myLocation"){
            location = mapView.myLocation.coordinate;

            self.mapView.animateToLocation(self.location!);
            self.mapView.animateToZoom(15);
            didOnce = true;
            self.mapView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "myLocation");
        }
    }
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    if(!didOnce){
        self.mapView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "myLocation");
        didOnce = true;
    }
}
```